# Maclaurin $f(x)=\sin^4x,x\in R$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

Write Maclaurin Polynomial$$T\small{10}(x)$$ for function 
$$f(x)=\sin^4x,x\in R$$

Maclaurin Polynomial: 
$$T10(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+f^{10}(0)\frac{x^{10}}{10!}$$

For my problem it means this?
$$f(0)=\sin^40 = 0 $$ 
$$+f'(0)=4\sin^30*\cos0 = 0$$
$$+f''(0)=12\sin^20*\cos0*\cos 0+4\sin^30(-\sin0) = 0+0 =0$$
$$+...$$
Is there any another way how can i get T10 Polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Using trigonometric identities, we can write

$$\sin^4 x=\frac38-\frac12 \cos(2x)+\frac18 \cos (4x)$$

Then, use the Taylor series for the cosine function

$$\cos z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, but i cannot get using trigoniometric identities same result as you write.  $$\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{4}cos^2(2x)$$ can you help me continue please?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!  Recall that $\cos^2(2x)=\frac{1+\cos (4x)}{2}$. - Mark

Comment: Thanks a lot! It means that next step will be: $$\frac38-\frac12 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\frac18 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ ? and n=10?

Comment: Not quite.  In the first series, replace $x$ with $2x$ and in the second series replace $x$ with $4x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
use the $$\sin^2 x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$$
$$\cos^2 x=\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}$$